# Array in c++ has many errors

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have the following lines of code that has many errors but I cant seem to find out how to fix it. The errors shown says that there are too many initializers and that the array must be initialized with a brace enclosed initializer. Can any one help??

```
const std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 8> m_rows =
    {{
        {0,3,6},
        {1,4,7},
        {2,5,8},
        {0,1,2},
        {3,4,5},
        {6,7,8},
        {0,4,8},
        {2,4,6}
    }};
```

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/380ef1f427c39f30)

Comment: both clang and gcc compile this without a problem

Comment: and please post the exact error message. Copy-paste is just a click away :)

Comment: Warning with clang [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a93b0de94cf2d29).

Comment: @Jarod42 oh, ok. So since clang-6 they removed the warning

Answer (score 2):

You might need extra `{}`:

```
const std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 8> m_rows =
{{
    {{0,3,6}},
    {{1,4,7}},
    {{2,5,8}},
    {{0,1,2}},
    {{3,4,5}},
    {{6,7,8}},
    {{0,4,8}},
    {{2,4,6}}
}};
```